# How to prevent display to turn on when tapping:Pixel 4a

Tags: lock-screens, google-pixel-4a

When I turn off the display of my Pixel 4A using the <kbd>power</kbd> button and tap the screen, the screen turns back on. It's locked and I have to slide the screen to unlock it. Still, from time to time the screen unlocks in my pocket because of this.

How can I prevent this? Is there a way I can configure the phone so that it *only* activates the screen when I press the power button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disable *tap to check phone* (Display →Lock Screen →Tap to check phone)